# Is this how a byte array look like?

Tags: perl, arrays

I am having difficulty trying to understand some data.

I have a Perl Script and all I know about that script is that it is sending some data packets over the network.

When I debug through the script the data that it sends looks like following: "KFD!P#"

I am very new to Perl  and all I know is that it should be a Byte[]. Should I not see something like \dsdsds \dssds if it is a byte array?

Is this string represented in any expression that I am not able to understand?

Any ideas?

Comment: `Byte[]` is a Java variable. Variables can't exist in packets. The packets contain a bunch of bytes (numbers between 0 to 255). You appear to simply dumped those bytes to a terminal, which expects text encoded with some character encoding, so it will treat what you send to it as such.

Comment: What kind of representation is `\dsdsds \dssds`?!

Comment: is there any way to declare or transform " "KFD!P#"" into byte array?

Comment: Define what you mean by "byte array". You want them the bytes as numbers? `unpack 'C*', $s`

Comment: "`KFD!P#`" is already an array of bytes. What you want is a textual representation of binary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the contents of a perl string that is being used as a buffer, you need to convert it to a printable form first. Use [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) for that.

For example to convert it to a string of hex digits:

```
print unpack('H*', $buffer),"\n";
```

Read [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Run wireshark to see what it is putting over the wire.

Any string can be considered a byte array so you won't need any keywords like "byte" in the code.

Sharing the code somewhere or some portion of it would provide more context to work with and address your question.